# Heat transfer between river and air

Tags: fluid-dynamics, water, air, weather

There is a temperature sensor about 200 feet back from a large river, at about the same height as the river. A sewage pipe continuously dumps water of about 12 degrees C in the river directly in front of the sensor. The volume dumped is enough to keep a several-hundred foot radius of the river from freezing in the winter (the rest of the river is frozen) .

My question is, when the air temperature away from the river from -6 C to +4 C, and the river's temperature is so cold as to produce a trick layer of ice away from the heated radius, could the heat from the nearby water be sufficient so as to raise the temperature of the air near the sensor to a degree or two Celsius above what it would be were there no sewage pipe?

This question relates to a pet project, an analysis of temperature anomalies recorded by a certain weather sensor. I am interested in general analyses and am happy to answer questions and provide more detail. Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to this community! I would say a sketch or maybe even a photo would help to understand the situation. Can you exclude other influences like sunlight, which could give you some unexpected temperature reading? Finally, don't mix units like Celsius and Fahrenheit. That's just unnecessary confusion.

Comment: Thank you! I will try to upload a diagram or picture soon. I am only interested in the (possible) effect of the river's temperature on the air's temperature near the sensor, so you can exclude other factors. I have changed the temperatures to C. Thank you.